# Tensoflow CPU: Allocation exceeds 10% of system memory

Tags: tensorflow, keras, bazel

I implemented a model in Keras using Tensorflow (CNN+RNN model). However, when I want to evaluate my model, I have the following error:

```
2018 09:48:44.961161: I tensorflow/core/platform     
/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

2018 09:49:00.450298: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101]    
Allocation of 3359939800 exceeds 10% of system memory.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what(): std::bad_alloc
```

It is a problem of CPU memory allocation but I don't know how to solve this issue. The parameters of my model are small so I don't think that's the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reducing the batch size or image size of your input data, or using a smaller model. Alternatively, you can also try increasing the amount of available memory on your system by adding more RAM or a GPU or more memeory machine